# AntBlazor unit testing with bUnit not working

Tags: blazor-server-side, bunit, ant-blazor

I'm fairly new to Blazor, AntBlazor, and bUnit.

When my test executes I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at AntDesign.Alert.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)

The component I am trying to test is making use of the *AntBlazor Alert* component.

```
<Alert Type="@AlertType.Error" Message="Error text" Closable class="mb-3" />
```

When it needs to show it throws that exception but when it doesn't need to show then the test passes.

I do register the AntDesign services with the TestContext

```
TestContext.Services.AddAntDesign();
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert or user of AntBlazor myself, so this is just what I found out while browsing through their code.

Registering the service does not seem enough. You see the error because of this line taken from [Alert.razor.cs](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/blob/master/components/alert/Alert.razor.cs):

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

    if (firstRender)
    {
        HtmlElement element = await JsInvokeAsync<HtmlElement>(JSInteropConstants.GetDomInfo, Ref);
        _height = element.ClientHeight;
    }
}
```

The JsInvoke will return a `null` element and therefore `element.ClientHeight`. will result in an `NullReferenceException`.
AntBlazor is providing a [`AntDesignTestContext`](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/blob/master/tests/AntDesign.TestKit/AntDesignTestBase.cs) you should inherit from. With that it should work.